# qemu kvm - can't start VMs after installing xen hypervisor

Tags: ubuntu, virtualization, kvm-switch, qemu, hypervisor

I had been using QEMU KVM for long time and have few VMs.

Recently I installed XEN Hypervisor following [this instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Xen) but decided to `apt-get remove xen-hypervisor-4.2-amd64`

Problem is that now, I can't use qemu-kmv anymore cause I get the following error when I try to start machines from `virt-manager`:

> Error starting domain: unsupported configuration: Domain requires KVM,
>   but it is not available. Check that virtualization is enabled in the
>   host BIOS, and host configuration is setup to load the kvm modules.
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 96, in
>   cb_wrapper
>       callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 117, in tmpcb
>       callback(*args, **kwargs)   File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1092, in startup
>       self._backend.create()   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 681, in create
>       if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self) libvirtError: unsupported configuration: Domain requires
>   KVM, but it is not available. Check that virtualization is enabled in
>   the host BIOS, and host configuration is setup to load the kvm
>   modules.

I have both `qemu-kvm` and `libvirt-bin` running:

```
# service qemu-kvm status
qemu-kvm start/running
# service libvirt-bin status
libvirt-bin start/running, process 10646
```

If you need more info please ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check if your kvm kernel module is still loaded, and if not load it.

lsmod | grep kvm

if you do not find it, do modprobe -v kvm (or maybe kvm-intel)

Comment: You are right, it wasn't Thanks a lot, I'll try again after restart

Comment: aleluja, it works after reboot, i did `sudo update-grub` in meanwhile, don't know if it was relevant. Thanks again :)